Accents don't work for me in Google Chrome
The accent keys, both normal and the inverted tilde, do not work for me in Google Chrome.
I don't know how to solve it, among other things, I read that some program may be interfering, but I don't believe it.

Versión 122.0.6261.128 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

How do I solve this?
xev
KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x408, subw 0x0, time 68079885, (48,-1), root:(1110,25),
    state 0x10, keycode 48 (keysym 0xfe51, dead_acute), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c2 b4) "´"
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: True

KeyPress event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x408, subw 0x0, time 68256708, (25,1), root:(1087,27),
    state 0x10, keycode 34 (keysym 0xfe50, dead_grave), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (60) "`"
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: True


ps -fe:
ps -s
 ~ 
ps -s
  UID     PID          PENDING          BLOCKED          IGNORED           CAUGHT STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
    0   17410 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000301000 00000000080b6a07 S+   tty1       0:00 sudo su
    0   17411 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000301000 0000000000096a07 Ss   pts/3      0:00 sudo su
    0   17412 0000000000000000 fffffffe7ffb9eff 0000000000000000 0000000000004000 S    pts/3      0:00 su
    0   17413 0000000000000000 0000000000010000 0000000000384004 000000004b813efb S    pts/3      0:00 sh
    0   17506 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 0000000100004003 Sl   pts/3      0:40 pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
    0   30657 0000000000000001 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 0000000100004000 Z    pts/3      0:06 [geany] <defunct>
    0   51012 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 0000000100004003 Sl   pts/3      0:00 pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
    0   52527 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000301000 00000000080b6a07 S+   pts/3      0:00 sudo su
    0   52528 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000301000 0000000000096a07 Ss   pts/4      0:00 sudo su
    0   52529 0000000000000000 fffffffe7ffb9eff 0000000000000000 0000000000004000 S    pts/4      0:00 su
    0   52530 0000000000000000 0000000000010000 0000000000384004 000000004b813efb S    pts/4      0:00 sh
    0   52680 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 0000000100004003 Sl   pts/4      0:06 pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
    0   66566 0000000000000001 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 0000000100004000 Z    pts/4      0:05 [geany] <defunct>
    0   69098 0000000000000000 0000000000010000 0000000000000004 0000000000010002 S+   pts/4      0:00 /bin/sh /bin/x
    0   69137 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000007207 S+   pts/4      0:00 /usr/bin/xinit /root/.xinitrc -- -br -nolisten tcp
    0   69138 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000301000 00000001418066ef S<sl+ tty2      0:20 /usr/libexec/Xorg :0 -br -nolisten tcp
    0   69144 0000000000010000 0000000000010000 0000000000000004 0000000000010002 S    pts/4      0:00 /bin/sh /bin/startlxde
    0   69183 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 0000000100000000 Sl   pts/4      0:00 /usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE -e LXDE
    0   69193 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000141b15edf Sl   pts/4      0:00 openbox --config-file /root/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
    0   69195 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 0000000100000000 Sl   pts/4      0:03 lxpanel --profile LXDE
    0   69203 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 0000000100000000 Sl   pts/4      0:00 /usr/libexec/geoclue-2.0/demos/agent
    0   69209 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 0000000100004202 Sl   pts/4      0:01 retrovol -hide
    0   69211 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 0000000000000000 S    pts/4      0:00 freememapplet_tray
    0   69237 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 0000000000000000 S    pts/4      0:00 parcellite
    0   69246 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 0000000100000000 Sl   pts/4      0:00 netmon_wce
    0   69328 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000006 0000000100000000 Sl   pts/4      0:00 pup-volume-monitor
    0   69565 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 0000000100004003 Sl   pts/4      0:01 pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
    0   69586 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 00000001418144ff S<l  pts/4      0:32 /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox --user-data-dir=/initrd/mnt/dev_save/chrome-sesion
    0   69590 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 S    pts/4      0:00 cat
    0   69591 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 S    pts/4      0:00 cat
    0   69599 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001002 0000000000010000 S    pts/4      0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --no-zygote-sandbox --no-sandbox --crashpad-handler-pid=0 --enable-crash-reporter=, --user-data-dir=/initrd/mnt/dev_save/chrome-sesion --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable
    0   69601 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001002 0000000000010000 S    pts/4      0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --no-sandbox --crashpad-handler-pid=0 --enable-crash-reporter=, --user-data-dir=/initrd/mnt/dev_save/chrome-sesion --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable
    0   69623 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001002 00000001018104fc Sl   pts/4      0:31 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-process --no-sandbox --crashpad-handler-pid=0 --enable-crash-reporter=, --user-data-dir=/initrd/mnt/dev_save/chrome-sesion --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --gpu-preferences=WAAAAAAAAAAgAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABgAAAAAAA4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAGAAAAAAAAAAYAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAACAAAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAA== --shared-files --field-trial-handle=0,i,627780694513956247,7696989949448210118,262144 --variations-seed-version=20240329-165146.919000
    0   69624 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001002 00000001018004fc Sl   pts/4      0:04 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=utility --utility-sub-type=network.mojom.NetworkService --lang=es-419 --service-sandbox-type=none --no-sandbox --crashpad-handler-pid=0 --enable-crash-reporter=, --user-data-dir=/initrd/mnt/dev_save/chrome-sesion --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,627780694513956247,7696989949448210118,262144 --variations-seed-version=20240329-165146.919000
    0   69625 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001002 00000001018104fc Sl   pts/4      0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=utility --utility-sub-type=storage.mojom.StorageService --lang=es-419 --service-sandbox-type=utility --no-sandbox --crashpad-handler-pid=0 --enable-crash-reporter=, --user-data-dir=/initrd/mnt/dev_save/chrome-sesion --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,627780694513956247,7696989949448210118,262144 --variations-seed-version=20240329-165146.919000
    0   69714 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001002 00000001018104fc S<l  pts/4      0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --crashpad-handler-pid=0 --enable-crash-reporter=, --user-data-dir=/initrd/mnt/dev_save/chrome-sesion --extension-process --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --no-sandbox --lang=es-419 --num-raster-threads=1 --renderer-client-id=7 --time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1711866793359275 --launch-time-ticks=68038554710 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,627780694513956247,7696989949448210118,262144 --variations-seed-version=20240329-165146.919000
    0   69725 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001002 00000001018104fc S<l  pts/4      0:02 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --crashpad-handler-pid=0 --enable-crash-reporter=, --user-data-dir=/initrd/mnt/dev_save/chrome-sesion --extension-process --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --no-sandbox --lang=es-419 --num-raster-threads=1 --renderer-client-id=8 --time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1711866793359275 --launch-time-ticks=68038646054 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,627780694513956247,7696989949448210118,262144 --variations-seed-version=20240329-165146.919000
    0   69729 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001002 00000001018104fc S<l  pts/4      0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --crashpad-handler-pid=0 --enable-crash-reporter=, --user-data-dir=/initrd/mnt/dev_save/chrome-sesion --extension-process --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --no-sandbox --lang=es-419 --num-raster-threads=1 --renderer-client-id=9 --time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1711866793359275 --launch-time-ticks=68038687846 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,627780694513956247,7696989949448210118,262144 --variations-seed-version=20240329-165146.919000
    0   69732 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001002 00000001018104fc S<l  pts/4      0:01 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --crashpad-handler-pid=0 --enable-crash-reporter=, --user-data-dir=/initrd/mnt/dev_save/chrome-sesion --extension-process --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --no-sandbox --lang=es-419 --num-raster-threads=1 --renderer-client-id=10 --time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1711866793359275 --launch-time-ticks=68038720792 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,627780694513956247,7696989949448210118,262144 --variations-seed-version=20240329-165146.919000
    0   69746 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001002 00000001018104fc S<l  pts/4      0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --crashpad-handler-pid=0 --enable-crash-reporter=, --user-data-dir=/initrd/mnt/dev_save/chrome-sesion --extension-process --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --no-sandbox --lang=es-419 --num-raster-threads=1 --renderer-client-id=11 --time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1711866793359275 --launch-time-ticks=68038765752 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,627780694513956247,7696989949448210118,262144 --variations-seed-version=20240329-165146.919000
    0   69849 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 0000000100000000 Sl   pts/4      0:05 lxterminal
    0   69850 0000000000000000 0000000000010000 0000000000384004 000000004b813efb Ss   pts/6      0:00 bash
    0   69996 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001002 00000001018104fc SNl  pts/4      0:24 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --crashpad-handler-pid=0 --enable-crash-reporter=, --user-data-dir=/initrd/mnt/dev_save/chrome-sesion --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --no-sandbox --lang=es-419 --num-raster-threads=1 --renderer-client-id=22 --time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1711866793359275 --launch-time-ticks=68131418488 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,627780694513956247,7696989949448210118,262144 --variations-seed-version=20240329-165146.919000
    0   70132 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001002 00000001018104fc SNl  pts/4      0:24 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --crashpad-handler-pid=0 --enable-crash-reporter=, --user-data-dir=/initrd/mnt/dev_save/chrome-sesion --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --no-sandbox --lang=es-419 --num-raster-threads=1 --renderer-client-id=31 --time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1711866793359275 --launch-time-ticks=68385107519 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,627780694513956247,7696989949448210118,262144 --variations-seed-version=20240329-165146.919000
    0   70157 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001002 00000001018104fc S<l  pts/4      0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --crashpad-handler-pid=0 --enable-crash-reporter=, --user-data-dir=/initrd/mnt/dev_save/chrome-sesion --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --no-sandbox --lang=es-419 --num-raster-threads=1 --renderer-client-id=34 --time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-1711866793359275 --launch-time-ticks=68391706093 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,627780694513956247,7696989949448210118,262144 --variations-seed-version=20240329-165146.919000
    0   70168 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001002 00000001018004fc Sl   pts/4      0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=utility --utility-sub-type=audio.mojom.AudioService --lang=es-419 --service-sandbox-type=none --no-sandbox --crashpad-handler-pid=0 --enable-crash-reporter=, --user-data-dir=/initrd/mnt/dev_save/chrome-sesion --change-stack-guard-on-fork=enable --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,i,627780694513956247,7696989949448210118,262144 --variations-seed-version=20240329-165146.919000
    0   70223 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 0000000100004000 Sl   pts/4      0:00 geany /root/Startup/reiniciar_panel.sh
    0   70228 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000384004 000000004b813efb Ss+  pts/7      0:00 /bin/sh
    0   70415 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 000000007391fef9 R+   pts/6      0:00 ps -s


I switched to Google Chrome 90 and the accent marks work.

Versión 90.0.4430.72 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

